# Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Comment: Robert, the certificate of meta is reported invalid: https://meta.devops.stackexchange.com/users

Comment: Yeah, @RomeoNinov, that's broken for all HTTPS links on all meta sites and has been forever and will be until we finish this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time

Answer (score 17):

I nominate Tensibai for Moderator Pro Tempore. Tensibai has been quite active here since the start, both on the main site (with 27 answers and 2 questions) and in meta (12 answers and 2 questions). Furthermore he is an experienced user on StackOverflow where he has a reputation of 11K+

[image]

[image]

[image]

I accept this nomination.

So I'm Tensibai, I live in France and I'm checking the site between 9 A.M. and 6 P.M. (GMT+1 or 2) during weekdays usually.

I hope my actions on main site, meta and chat show I feel concerned by this site and that I'm open to discussion. Feel free to browse my network profile to have a wider idea about me and I'll answer any questions in comments if there's some.

Comment: Wow, thanks, really, I'm glad to be nominated by someone.... let me till tomorrow to make my mind about it, too late to take a decision like this right now.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I think it will be at least a few days before the SE staff will appoint the moderators.

Comment: Yes I'm sure we have plenty of time, but it's nearly 10pm here and the day was exhausting, my first reaction has been to start with editing for a ok, but I think I'd better take a night over it to be sure I can handle the responsibility on midterm with a fresh mind :)

Comment: You have as much time as you need to find a way to rationalize editing "accept" into this answer, @Tensibai.

Comment: I have nothing to do with DevOps but I know Tens for a few years now (from SO - where we are trying to moderate some tags together using a chat room) and I must say he is very level headed, professional, rational, always ready to help- in short I think he will be a great mod.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

[image]
[image]

#### Notes:

I think I would be a good choice because I have experience with maintaining, and help maintain several sites. This also includes several private beta SE-sites (where I have also fulfilled my commitment from Area51), such as:

- [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/101/dawny33).
- [Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/23/dawny33).
- [HardwareRecommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/313/dawny33).

Also, I have actively contributed in maintaining and help maintain sites like [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/11097/dawny33), [WorkPlace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/40657/dawny33), [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/84191/dawny33) and [Startups SE](https://startups.stackexchange.com/users/5834/dawny33) and have [several](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/11097/dawny33?tab=badges) [moderation](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/40657/dawny33?tab=badges) [badges](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/84191/dawny33?tab=badges) to prove the same.

[Here is a link to my site-wide activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/6444670/dawny33?tab=activity) on StackExchange.

I can commit to moderating across the Asia (Mumbai) IST timezone.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Added links to my profiles in all the sites.  But, by all means, please go ahead and make any edits if you think they'll be constructive. :)

Comment: Please review my edit of your answer (I didn't change the actual content, of course, only adapted the formatting a bit). If you don't like it at all, just perform a rollback. Good luck!

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Perfect. It looks better.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

[image]

[image: profile for Pierre.Vriens at DevOps Meta Stack Exchange]

#### About

- He often helps improving questions/answers on drupal.SE, via actions such as:

  - Add comments to clarify questions.
  - Edit question tags to correct the tagging.
  - Edit posts to fix typos/grammar, or to add relevant links, or to help improve answers.
  - Create/edit tag wikis and/or wiki excerpts.
- He already contributed quite a lot to this (private beta) DevOps site, and related meta-site ... Just check the stats about [Editors](https://devops.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors), [Voters](https://devops.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all), [Reputation](https://devops.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) and [Review queues](https://devops.stackexchange.com/review).
- He is the top reviewer in each and every [review queue at Drupal.SE](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review).
- His availability seems to be virtually unlimited (close to 7d/7d and 24h/24h, all year around).

#### Area of expertise

- He has lots of DevOps expertise, for topics such as [scm](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scm), [configuration](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration), etc ... [read more](https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/40/pierre-vriens?tab=tags).
- "[How to use the Features module in a 3 dev environment?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199206/how-to-use-the-features-module-in-a-3-dev-environnement)" applies his DevOps to Drupal.

#### Time for a walk

His passion, apart from SCM and gardening, seems to be a special breeds of dogs. These passions are reflected also in his profile pictures (which occasionally change).

And if he ever posts a comment like "*Time for a walk (with my profile picture)!*", then be ready for some illuminating answers (or interesting questions) that may follow soon.

#### Recommendation

For all reasons mentioned above, I think this nominee would be a great choice ...

Trust me ... and use this public beta period for [testing](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing) it yourself.

> I, Pierre.Vriens, <kbd>accept</kbd> this nomination.
>
> I am from the land of Beer, Chocolats, Fries and ... where the DevOps-term appears to have been introduced first (so I was told ...). I got involved with mainframe SCM about a decade before Y2K became a thing. Who remembers the DevOps challenges from around then?
>
> It's hard to tell when I am generally NOT active on me favorite SE-sites (DevOps.SE is one of them). Refer to my (1st) comment to this answer to get an idea about how I think about things like voting or answering.
>
> I've never been a mod on any SE-site, so consider me at your own risk. May the stats posted by @Adrian, and the metrics that @Tensibai mentioned in a comment here, help you to do your own research about this risk.
>
> **Note**: I wonder (not worry ...) about the reasons for the *anonymous* downvotes (for ALL candidates). But, similar to handling support calls: if we don't understand the problem, we cannot (try to) fix it. So after yet another *walk with my profile picture*, I've decided to just ignore those votes.

---

> **Update**: This is how the [Candidate score](http://data.stackexchange.com/devops/query/298418/candidate-score?UserIds=13%2C40%2C46%2C47%2C57%2C72) looked like as of April 2, 2017:

```
User Link    Total CappedRep BadgeCount ModBadges EditingBadges ParticipationBadges

Pierre.Vriens   10         1          9         2             4                   3
Tensibai         8         2          6         0             3                   3
Dan Cornilescu   6         1          5         0             2                   3
Dawny33          4         0          4         0             2                   2
Dave Swersky     2         1          1         0             0                   1
Romeo Ninov      1         0          1         0             0                   1
```

Comment: Beat on time, was collecting some interesting metrics on Pierre but seems you know him better than me ;)

Comment: I see two downvotes in this nominations but I can't see the reasons in the comments. If we want to improve the community we need to says what is wrong or what should be improved.

Comment: @Tensibai Feel free to edit the nominations with your point of view.

Comment: I don't get it either, but I see not much to add

Comment: Merci for your post Adrian! I may not be as good as you wrote, but I do like exchanging knowledge using SE sites. And possibly help other users with their problems. Also, IMO it's so easy to vote-to-close (or downvote) a question (or answer), but it's way more difficult to challenge/motivate a user to try to improve their post (at the risk they don't like or get it). And I consider questions that I answer as a way to *continuously test" (oeps!) my own knowledge.". PS:  **Time for a walk ...**, eg to think about @Tensibai 's comments (like about those metrics).

Comment: @Pierre metrics are those showing an interest in moderation, flag raised, percent deemed helpful, vote behavior, meta posts and their tone. Just things showcasing the interest on moderation and about quality of posts

Comment: I didn't downvote Pierre's nomination, but I did downvote 1 or 2 of his rather broad early questions which he immediately answered himself. I know self-answering is allowed on SE sites, but I think it should be limited to posting solutions to practical problems you encountered. I can imagine the self-answering turned off other people as well.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens has been one of the most helpful folks on this site. Helped me with a lot of excellent answers and also formatting.  (+1)

Comment: @THelper DankJeWel (oeps: thank you) for your constructive comment also. You seem to confirm what I was hesitating about myself also, and I'm still trying to find a good balance, or to hear from others which part/kind of my expertise might help to improve the site content. The toughest part, IMO, it to write the appropriate question. So consider it as my attempts to do some ***private*** beta experiments, to see what works, and what not. But the only way to find out (and help "me"), is to leave comments when downvoting. Snappie (aka "Get it")? PS to Dan: still want to know my bank-down-story?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Experimenting is fine, but in my opinion it's best to do this in a more mature site, not now in private beta. At this stage we need good example questions and answers to show people the kind of posts we want and value. You're right that I should have communicated this sooner.

Comment: I support @Pierre.Vriens nomination for moderator. Have been seeing his great works on Drupal.SE. (+1)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hi, I'm Dan, I live in Canada and I'm a Continuous Integration nut.

I'd be honoured to be a Moderator Pro Tempore until proper elections can take place. I closely followed the most recent 2 incarnations of the proposal and I'd like to help make DevOps one of the most popular StackExchange (SE) sites.

My schedule is flexible, I'm often online between 9am - 3pm and 10pm - midnight EST on weekdays and randomly during weekends, so I can get a pretty good coverage of the Americas' activity.

Ex hardware designer, ex embedded software developer. Work experience on both `dev` and `ops`. I'd call myself a devops guy, if such role would actually exist ;)

The bulk of my SE reputation comes from [Google App Engine related posts on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A4495081%20%5Bgoogle-app-engine%5D). My curating SE activities so far have been solely from a regular user position, I didn't yet use the moderator tools (other than the shortcut for tags edits). So there will be a bit of a learning curve for me.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I'd like to volunteer for Moderator Pro Tem of the DevOps StackExchange site.  I'm active on the site every day.  I'm in the American Central time zone.

I've been working intensively in DevOps and Agile for three years.  I've presented on DevOps at conferences including the DevOps Enterprise Summit in 2014. I have been a StackOverflow user since the beta in 2008.  I am also writing a book about DevOps tools:

http://devopskatas.com

Most of my experience in moderation comes from answering/asking on StackOverflow for the last eight years. I'm active on SO in closing questions that can't be answered, commenting on questions that can be "saved" with a little more clarification, and spot-editing questions that need a little spelling/grammatical help.

Thank you for your consideration!

Comment: Hi Dave! Thank you for stepping forward. I see you are quite active on Stack Overflow, but can you tell us a bit about your moderation/site maintenance experience?

Comment: Most of my experience in moderation comes from answering/asking on StackOverflow for the last eight years.  I'm active on SO in closing questions that can't be answered, commenting on questions that can be "saved" with a little more clarification, and spot-editing questions that need a little spelling/grammatical help.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because I have wide areas of knowledge and count myself as wise person.

My areas of interest and participation in SE sites include:

- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/101265/romeo-ninov) where I have reputation >1600. On this site I also
  participate in review ( by reputation >1000) with First Posts review
  = 272, Late answers = 55
- [superuser](https://superuser.com/users/409497/romeo-ninov) where I have reputation >1100. On this site I also
  participate in review (by reputation >1000) with First Posts review
  = 1962, Late answers = 417
- [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/77753/romeo-ninov) where I have reputation >500. On this site I also
  participate in review (by reputation >500) of First Posts and Late answers
- DevOps I also participate in review (by reputation >200) with Close Votes = 23, Reopen Votes = 19

I have in my answers [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182032/zip-the-contents-of-a-folder-without-including-the-folder-itself/182036#182036), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183063/local-installation-of-rpms-using-yum/183064#183064), [3](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90972/are-there-any-downsides-to-using-lets-encrypt-for-a-websites-ssl-certificates/90977#90977) with upvotes more than 10 (in Unix and Security)

My timezones are: CET (GMT+1) and EET (GMT+2) (50/50)

P.S. Just for the record I also participate in [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/34947/romeo-ninov) where my reputation is 1274 with First Posts review = 1086, Late answers = 349

P.P.S. I am Global Moderator in one local forum with >200k users and (almost) 3M posts. My duties include approve, delete, edit posts, move, combine, split articles and so on

Comment: Does your knowledge include site moderation? And what experience do you have with site maintenance activities on this or other SE sites?

Comment: @THelper, yes, I have good experience of moderation (not on SE site(s), but for more than 6-7 years). No, I do not have experience with site maintenance on SE site(s)

Comment: Hey Romeo, I think you should try to improve/expand your own answer. Why not also explain a bit about your contributions in "Unix & Linux", and/or Super User? Or add some details about that moderation on none-SE sites. If it would help you, why not "steal" whatever fits from any other answer, and tweak it to fit for you. Also, I think it could be appropriate also to remind others about your ranking in the review queues that you have gained access to so far. Extra question: what about tag edit suggestions (if any?). Ping me if you want/need help or feedback. Try it!